# Regex for key value in java

Tags: java, regex

i'm trying to create a regExp for this strings in java :

```
key:value
key:"value" 
key:'value' 
key : value  
key :"value 123" 
key: 'value 123'
```

every condition can be in a single line :

```
key:value key : value key : "value 123"
```

i've to match each of them, capturing key and value, trimmed and without quotes.

unfortunately java does not support conditionals in regex.

Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dont understand your question.

Comment: you want the the strings to become in a single line ? (because I did not understand what you aree realy looking for)

Comment: Can you please supply an example of INPUT and the desired OUTPUT that match your needs? Your question is not that much clear.

Comment: My matcher must have multiple find with 2 group each, key and value.

Comment: Not working sample : ([\w\d]+)\s*:\s*(.+)
because if i have multiple find on a single line it matches all the line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should suit your needs ([demo](http://regexr.com?34ah2)):

```
(\w+)\s*:\s*((?:.(?!\w+\s*(?<!\\):))*)
```

The first group contains the key, the second one the value.

I added a way to manage the nested `:` in the values: just escape them with `\`.

You'll still have to trim the results though.

Comment: maybe adding \s* ? (\\w+)\\s*:\\s*((?:.(?!\\w+\\s*:))*)

Answer (score 1):

This pattern should satisfy those requirements:

```
(\w+)( *):( *)(\w+|(["'])([\w\s]+)\5)
```

Comment: it does not match key:"value or key:value'

Comment: Hmmm. Fixed a mistake in it. But I'm not sure what pair it should find for the value you've commented. The regex I have now finds the second one and ignores the first. Is that what you want? I am not sure whether you're asking about the nested key value pair or the mismatched quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following regex:

```
/(\w+)\s*:\s*(((['"]).+?\4)|\w+)/
```

Group # 1 will be your key and Group # 2 will be value.

#### Live Demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/IPqtdneBeW